# Allow Ampersand in mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, ampersand

I am trying to allow '&' in my mod_rewrite.
at the moment i am using

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_'_-]+)$
```

I tried adding:

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_'_-_&]+)$
```

to allow ampersand, yet i know it is most likey wrong. can anyone direct me in the right direction for the correct regex layout.

Comment: Did you try `^([a-zA-Z0-9'&]+)$`?

Comment: that worked like a charm! Thanks very much! this always confuses me.

Comment: It seems I forgot the underscore and the hyphen. Add those somewhere outside character groups (group1:`a-z`, group2:`A-Z`, group3:`0-9`) but inside the square brackets, if you want those as well. Example: `^([a-zA-Z0-9'&_-]+)$`

Answer (score 1):

You also must escape the hyphen because it indicates range for matching inside square brackets (it doesn't fail because you included it last but in other cases it would have like in OP).

Proper escaping of hyphen:
`^([a-zA-Z0-9'&_\-]+)$`

this would fail: `^([a-zA-Z0-9'_-&]+)$`

this would not: `^([a-zA-Z0-9'_\-&]+)$`

(i would have commented but my rep is not high enough)